# Passing HttpContext.Current in MyDelegate.BeginInvoke doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates, begininvoke

I am trying to pass HttpContext.Current to a delegate.
The value is well set before the delegate is executed, once I run it with BeginInvoke the value turns to null.
Any idea why this happens?
Is there any way around this?

Comment: Some code would definitely promote an answer.

Answer (score 2):

if your delegate runs on a different thread, then the HttpContext.Current is on a different context and thus it can't be retrieved. try sending the data you want from the HttpContext.Current and not the actual HttpContext.Current